# Динамически конвертировать в тип и производить операцию сравнение сконвертированых значений

Tags: c#, алгоритм, типы, dynamic

Есть набор значений, которые парсятся отдельно и заполняются в список `List<string> compareValues`.

Также есть значение `value` с которым нужно сравнивать список значений.

Значение может быть `decimal` (2.50), `int`(10), `Date`(31/07/2018 or 7-31-2018 etc) или `string`.

Для операций есть `enum` который имеет вид:

```
public enum CompareOperation
{
    [Description("=")]
    Equal,
    [Description("<>")]
    NotEqual,
    [Description(">")]
    Greater,
    [Description(">=")]
    GreaterOrEqual,
    [Description("<")]
    Less,
    [Description("<=")]
    LessOrEqual
}
```

Значение операции также парсится отдельно.

Нужно написать метод, который будет производить операцию соответствующего сравнения и возращать `true` или `false`.

В моем решении много копипасты и вопрос в том, можна ли реализовать данную задачу более "правильно" чтобы избежать копипасты?

```
private bool CompareCondition(List<string> compareValues, string value, CompareOperation operation)
{
    int intVal;
    decimal decimalVal;
    DateTime datetimeVal;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case CompareOperation.Equal:
        {

            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => intVal == Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {                        
                return compareValues.Any(x => decimalVal == Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => datetimeVal == DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => x == value);
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.NotEqual:
        {   
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => intVal != Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => decimalVal != Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => datetimeVal != DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.Greater:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal > Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal > Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal > DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.GreaterOrEqual:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal >= Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal >= Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal >= DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.Less:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal < Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal < Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal < DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.LessOrEqual:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal <= Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal <= Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal <= DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам вообще приведение типов делать, почему просто как строки не сравнивать? У вас `value` - строка и в `compareValues` строки. Как минимум, для сравнения на равенства.

Comment: Можно попробовать собрать Expression и скомпилировать его в лямбду

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если будет мало вызовов скомпилированной лямбды, то затраты на компиляцию могут оказаться выше, чем просто куча условий

Comment: @Grundy Затраты здесь в любом случае выше, но автору нужно код сократить или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, А будет ли код сборки expression короче?

Comment: @Grundy На пару строк будет, но точно не будет понятнее :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну не, больше пары строк можно тут убрать просто записав условия в одну строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу смысла отдельно сравнивать int, можно сразу преобразовывать в decimal, на результат это не повлияет. DateTime и decimal реализуют интерфейс IComparable.

```
        private bool CompareCondition(List<string> compareValues, string value, CompareOperation operation)
        {
            if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal @decimal))
            {
                //тут я не понял, какая часть у вас должна быть левой, а какая правой, CompareOperation.Less тут означает, что все элементы в compareValues меньше чем value, а не то, что value меньше всех элеменов в compareValues
                return compareValues.Any(x => CompareTo(Decimal.Parse(x), @decimal, operation));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTime))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None), dateTime, operation));
            }
            else
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => x == value);
            }
        }

        private bool CompareTo<T>(T left, T right, CompareOperation operation) where T : IComparable
        {
            switch (operation)
            {
                case CompareOperation.Equal: return left.CompareTo(right) == 0;
                case CompareOperation.NotEqual: return left.CompareTo(right) != 0;
                case CompareOperation.Greater: return left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
                case CompareOperation.GreaterOrEqual: return left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
                case CompareOperation.Less: return left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
                case CompareOperation.LessOrEqual: return left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться, например текстовым парсером типа [Irony](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=irony). Ссылка [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029699/c-sharp-convert-string-expression-to-a-boolean-expression). Но в таком случае задача только усложниться и производительность упадёт. 
Ваш код хоть и копипастен, но быстр, поэтому можно чуть улучшить читаемость без вреда для производительности. "Правильным" мой способ не назовёшь, слишком специфичная задача.

Создаёте такой словарь (остальные делаете по образу и подобию).

```
public static Dictionary<CompareOperation, Func<int, int, bool>> DicInt = new Dictionary<CompareOperation, Func<int, int, bool>>()
{
    { CompareOperation.Equal,          (left, rigth)=> {return left == rigth; } },
    { CompareOperation.NotEqual,       (left, rigth)=> {return left != rigth; } },
    { CompareOperation.Greater,        (left, rigth)=> {return left >  rigth; } },
    { CompareOperation.GreaterOrEqual, (left, rigth)=> {return left >= rigth; } },
    { CompareOperation.Less,           (left, rigth)=> {return left <  rigth; } },
    { CompareOperation.LessOrEqual,    (left, rigth)=> {return left <= rigth; } }
};
```

Используете:

```
private static bool CompareCondition(List<string> compareValues, string value, CompareOperation operation)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int intVal))
    {
        var func = DicInt[operation];
        return compareValues.Any(x => func(intVal, Int32.Parse(x)));
    }
    else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal decimalVal))
    {
        var func = DicDec[operation];
        return compareValues.Any(x => func(decimalVal, Decimal.Parse(x)));
    }
    else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime datetimeVal))
    {
        var func = DicDate[operation];
        return compareValues.Any(x => func(datetimeVal, DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)));
    }
    else
    {
        return compareValues.Any(x => x == value);
    }
}
```

В дальнейшем вы можете использовать эти же словари в других частях программы.

UPD: Как подсказал B. Vandyshev в комментариях, можно пропустить этап с парсингом integer и сразу переходить к decimal, так как диапазон int полностью влезает в диапазон значений decimal.

```
private static bool CompareCondition(List<string> compareValues, string value, CompareOperation operation)
{
    if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal decimalVal))
    {
        var func = DicDec[operation];
        return compareValues.Any(x => func(decimalVal, Decimal.Parse(x)));
    }
    else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime datetimeVal))
    {
        var func = DicDate[operation];
        return compareValues.Any(x => func(datetimeVal, DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)));
    }
    else
    {
        return compareValues.Any(x => x == value);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему нужно именно сначала пытаться парсить в int? Почему сразу не парсить в decimal?

Comment: Эта часть кода не моя, взял у автора вопроса для примера. А вообще вы правы, но это уже нужно автору скорее говорить, а так сейчас добавлю вариант.